# Forecasting with two rank correlated data sets

Tags: correlation, forecasting, svm, prediction, supervised-learning

I have a machine that produces widgets.  I know the more widgets the machine produces the more heat it produces.  When I observe the machine I see the following temperatures:

[20,21,19,25,30,40,45,47,48,46,44,31,24,21,20,20]

while at the same time I'm producing the following number of widgets

[40,40,40,50,60,70,75,75,75,75,70,60,50,40,40,40]

I want to maximize machine output.  I know i can safely operate the machine up to a temperature of 100.  What is the best way for me to predict the most number of widgets I can produce if I set a target temperature of 95?

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  Is it?  What have you tried?

Comment: Not a homework problem.  It’s a simplified version of a much larger problem.  We are trying to calculate the point of resource exhaustion in computers.  Finding the limiting factors and breaking points programmatically.  The real problem has way more dimensions and lots of other moving parts, but I was hoping to at least get an introduction to where I should focus my studying.  Complex ML didn’t quite seem to fit properly so I was hoping to get pointed in the direction of a more stats based approach.  I’ve been reading about basic forecasting algorithms.